# Entity Framework many to many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to figure out how to structure my Entities properly for the following scenario.
I have three entities, Department, Employee, Wage. Each employee can be in many departments and every department has a many wages for each employee. My Linq query will only take the most recent wage (by id) for an employee in a department.
My ultimate goal is to get every department and most recent wage for a specific employee.
This is what I currently have. Is there a better way to structure this?

```
 public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Wage> Wages { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Wage> Wages { get; set; }
}
public class Wage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

The Linq query I am trying use to pull all departments and wages for a specific Employee.

```
Employees
  .Where(e => e.EmployeeId.Equals(12345))
  .SelectMany(e => e.Departments)
```

This returns all of the departments that are associated with a specific employee. Now I need to figure out how to display only the newest wage associated with that department/employee combo. Currently it brings back all of the wage entities.

Ultimately trying to bring the following fields out in the results with the Wages Entity (highlighted in yellow) replaced with a single field "Amount" from the Wages entity.
[image: Department.Name/(most recent)Wages.Amount]

Comment: do you mean the current configuration works fine but you need some ***better*** way?

Comment: is there a cycle here ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with what you currently have...

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: I've been having trouble crafting a Linq query to pull the departments with current wages. So I thought there might be a better way to craft the entities.

Comment: the model you have should be fine for using Linq, if you have some difficulty using linq, you should add some example showing the problem instead.

Comment: You said ***pull all departments and wages for a specific Employee*** - but what you did in the query is for ***all*** Employees in a company. Each employee already exposes 2 nav properties to get the related `Departments` and `Wages` so it should be easy. Otherwise you have not explained your purpose well (the query you wrote is even wrong, there will be duplicated Departments and I believe that's not what we usually want).

Comment: I'm not sure where you see that is pulling all employees. The where clause is limiting the employees by their unique companyId. (CompanyId is the employee's company assigned ID not the ID of a company). Working with live data I'm also never getting duplicated Departments. Can you elaborate a bit so I can see the issues? Thanks

Comment: BTW looks like you are trying to query for all employees in a company with this `Employees.Where(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345))`, so you should have some `Companies` entity set from which you can filter for a specific company and get all its employees via some nav property. Also you did not post the `CompanyId` foreign key property in your `Employee` class.

Comment: I said ***all Employees in a company***. You don't have duplidate data but you may have in future. E.g: employeeA and employeeB are in the same Department, so `SelectMany(e => e.Departments)` will result in 2 duplicate Departments.

Comment: Unfortunately the field is named CompanyID but represents the employee's ID. This is an unfortunate naming coincidence but for business processes they have 3 different IDs. i.e. Company Id, Account Id, Security Id. There is no Company entity involved my query.

Comment: @JohnS well, so it was confusing to me when you use `CompanyId` here, if as what you explained, then it's unique for each employee? If so it should be employeeId. Anyway why don't you use navigation property `Departments` of `Employee`?

Comment: I understand that it is a confusing name but that is out of my hands because it is a business defined internal term. I renamed it in my example query.

Comment: If it's unique then this `Employees.Where(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345))` should be `Employees.Single(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345))`, and then you can get its departments via the nav property like this `Employees.Single(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345)).Departments`

Comment: Ok Corrected the query according to your suggestions. That works well. Now the last piece is pulling the most recent wage for the department.employee combination.

Comment: it is unclear on how a wage is considered as ***most recent***? I don't see any DateTime property in `Wage` so that we could filter on that criteria.

Comment: Most recent wage is indicated by highest Id. I thought about adding a DateTime property but it seemed like extra data considering that the ID is auto-incrementing. And queries on the PK should be faster then a datetime field.

Comment: so each Department should have just 1 most recent wage, you can use `OrderByDescending` and select the first Wage using `First`.

Comment: Yes but having issues figuring out how to bring the Wage table into the query.

Comment: we simply use nav properties. I don't really understand what you want, it looks like a composite info so it's better to update your question with detailed info (we may need to project the result into an anonymous object). Otherwise you may want to use multiple queries, such as firstly query for `Departments`, then for most recent Wages (because each department has one most recent wage, it has some kind of 1-1 mapping, so we use a simple projection to translate Department to Wage: e.g: `...Departments.Select(e => e.Wages.OrderByDescending(k=>k.Id).First())`